# store string and integer type CSV file into a matrix matlab

Tags: string, matlab, csv, matrix, textscan

I have a CSV file that has 3 columns having : 
    String type(This can be a word or a sentence),  integer type,  integer type [these are the column types]
Now I want to store this data into a matrix,where the string(the whole sentence is stored into one cell)and the integers in one cell each too. I tried this:

```
fileID=fopen('training.csv');
C=textscan(fileID,'%s %d %d');
```

But it gives each word of the sentence in a different cell!The whole sentecne should be stored in one cell.How do I do that?

Thank you.

**EDIT**:It does seem to read anything now,this is what I get

```
celldisp(C)

C{1}{1} =

     jdl 

C{2} =

     []   

C{3} =

     []
```

**EDIT**:

```
jdl h-yf u ghjktnfhcrjuj hjcljd-yf-ljye                 129771  196
EAS CJDTNCRBH YFIRJHNJCNFY UJH HTDL HTCG                819100  458
rcfcyjzcrjuj rfycrf u rhfz edl                          547653  677
trfcthbyyehuf h-yt jnltkjv eavc xrfkjdcrjv u hjccbb d   970121  884
H-YF TRFNTHBYYEHUF U EDL XRFKJDCRJUJ                    938870  630
jdl yfhyfek h-yf rtktpyjljhjryjuj                       525855  598
rhfcyjzhcrf eghfdktybtv dyenhtyybq hfqjyf u ktybycrjuj  709215  403
```

Pretty much looks like this.It has 3500 rows of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the strings into quotation marks and then use %q in textscan:

```
%q  String, where double quotation marks indicate text to keep together
```

**EDIT**: If you only need to do that once (and not automatically via script in another process), what about manually importing the data from the CSV-File into MATLAB (via the import-tool provided by matlab:

[image])

and then maybe save the imported variables simply to a MAT-file so you can access it easier in the future!?

Comment: coukd you elaborate,I dont undertsand what you are saying.Should I modify the file I have? the file has 1000 rows.

Comment: Yeah what I meant was to export the data into a csv-file where the strings are between quotation marks, e.g. look like something like this: "bla bla bla";1;2 and then you could use the parameter %q in textscan to match the strings inbetween quotation marks. But that would only be an option if you could modify the csv-file easily (e.g. by changing the output routine of the program which outputs the csv-file). Where does the csv-file come from (generated from what)?

Comment: Given by my university.Its a training data i need to import into matlab to work on(Machine learning).It has 3 columuns and many many rows.The first column has a sentence.And im stuck wondering how i can import that first column as a first column in a matrix in matlab.

Comment: Oh okay then it's probably not easily possible to convert the format. So this solution isn't for you. Could you upload the csv-file?

Comment: Yeah I can.is it possible to upload here or should I use external link?

Comment: Thank you! I used the import button ,but if I were to write a script would it still work to use the import button?

Comment: If you'd want to always import the sama data within your trainig script, I sugest to manually import it once and save the imported data to a mat-file which you can easily load in MATLAB via `load('bla.mat')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel, you can use [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html). You can also try [`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html).

Comment: I dont have office.I have a mac